# Microsoft Graph API - @odata.nextLink is not returned in messages/delta response due to invalid JSON response and ErrorCannotOpenFileAttachment error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm making a request to the Microsoft Graph API to the `messages/delta` endpoint, and seeing invalid JSON being returned as a result of an `ErrorCannotOpenFileAttachment` error, which is also causing the `@odata.nextLink` property to be missing from the response.

Example request:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Ruby
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer {some_token}
Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=1
Connection: keep-alive

GET /v1.0/me/mailFolders('{some_folder_id}')/messages/delta?$skiptoken={some_skip_token}
```

Example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true; IEEE754Compatible=false; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
request-id: f1cb18ba-cf86-4060-8ad9-82e7c31bb2ec
client-request-id: f1cb18ba-cf86-4060-8ad9-82e7c31bb2ec
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US 2","Slice":"E","Ring":"1","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"MW2PEPF0000E53D"}}
Date: Thu, 10 Aug 2023 14:10:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(message)","value":[{"error":{"code":"ErrorCannotOpenFileAttachment","message":"The attachment could not be opened."}}
```

You can see that the JSON response is missing the closing square bracket for the `value` property and does not include the `@odata.nextLink` (or `@odata.deltaLink`) property.

I set the `Prefer` header to `odata.maxpagesize=1` narrow down the response to a single record.

Is there away to ignore this error that appears to be caused by a single, perhaps malformed email or attachment, and continue on to the next page of the delta request? Or is there a way to filter out specific message Ids from the `messages/delta` request?

It looks like a similar scenario was raised here: [Microsoft Graph API - Filter messages response contains invalid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74364919/microsoft-graph-api-filter-messages-response-contains-invalid-json)